# How to convert a random number to its corresponding letter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, random

I have looked up this and not found anything usefule
So I want to take a unknown number (1-26) and convert it to its corrosponding letter.

Example:

```
import random
rand_let = random.randint(1,26)
print(rand_let)
#Insert the numb letter converter here
print(rand_let) # This is the changed version
output: 
3
C
```

Comment: let me look at that

Comment: At first that seems like the opposite of this question, but the accepted answer explains how to do it in both directions.

Comment: I took a look at that  Ill try using it

Comment: I took a look and I will be using that, thank you for showing me that post as I did not know how the ASCII table worked

Comment: If you don't need the random number for anything else: `random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)`.

Comment: @martineau's solution would be imo definitely the way to go (note that you need to `import string` for that one before).

Answer (score 5):

`chr()` is your converter function. There is an offset of 64, as the numbers to be used are from the ASCII table of characters (i.e.: A = 65, B = 66, ...):

```
# import random
# rand_let = random.randint(1,26)
# print(rand_let)
rand_let = chr(rand_let + 64)
# print(rand_let) # This is the changed version
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could solve this problem is by making a bunch of if thens like so:

```
if rand_let == 1:
    print("A")
```

Another simple way is to make a list of letters and then ask for the letter with a rand_let - 1 index (because the 1st thing in a list has an index of 0.

```
LetterList = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", and so on...]
letter = LetterList[rand_let-1]
print(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this. First you can create a dictionary and assign letters as numbers. another way would be to find the chr() code number then use a random number generater to pick a char num. This is what I recommend.

```
# imports
import random
# pick a random number between the ord of 'a' and the ord of 'z' Google these for 
# more info
pick = random.randint(ord('a'), ord('z'))
# print the char of the ord of the random number picked
print(chr(pick))
```